How to import custom files in the same folder as main.py
Suppose I have:
Project_root (folder)
   source (folder)
   main.py
      functions(folder)
         test.py
         __init__.py (empty)

Here is the code in main.py:
import os
import sys
from source.functions import test
test.hello()

Code in test.py:
def hello():
   print("Hello World!")

I'm running this on vs code with anaconda virtual environment. I'm using tensorflow-directml-plugin.
The Error I get is:
line 4, in <module>
from source.functions import test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source'

I have tried to import when both the python files are in the same folder and it worked. I also succeeded when the main.py was directly in the root folder but not in a folder that was UNDER the root folder. In this case the main.py is in a folder that is in the root folder and it fails.

This question is similar to: How to import a python file that is in the same directory as the file I am trying to run from outside of that directory?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Python should not let a user do this as it could create a circular reference.

Files named __init__.py are used to mark directories on disk as Python package directories. If you have the files
.
├── main.py (file)
└── source (folder)
    └── functions (folder)
        ├── __init__.py (file)
        └── test.py (file)

test.py
def hello():
print("Hello World!")

main.py
from source.functions import test
test.hello()

Running main.py
> python main.py
Hello World!

